# Программа проходит не все тесты C

Tags: c, массивы

**Задание**:

В массиве из N элементов (N < 20) типа unsigned long long
найти максимальный из полных квадратов и напечатать его индекс (начиная с нуля).
Если нет ни одного полного квадрата, напечатать -1.
Если максимальных более одного, напечатать индекс первого из них.

Примечание. Полным квадратом называется число, являющееся квадратом
некоторого целого числа, например: 4, 9, 16.

Входные данные: стандартный поток ввода, где
на первой строке записано N
на второй строке элементы массива через пробел

Выходные данные: число в стандартном потоке вывода

**Код**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//Проверка числа из массива на полный квадрат
int is_num_pef_sqrt(long long int x) {
    
    unsigned short int tr_or_fl = 0;

    double value = (double)x;
    double root = sqrt(value);
    if (root * root == value) {
    
        tr_or_fl = 1;

    }
    
    return tr_or_fl;
   
}

int main() {

    unsigned short int n, noswap,  count = 0;
    unsigned long long int mass[20], mass_copy[20];
    unsigned long long int max = 0;
  
    int tmp;

    scanf("%hu", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { scanf("%llu", &mass[i]); }

    //Создание копии массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { mass_copy[i] = mass[i]; }
    
    //Сортировка пузырьком
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        noswap = 1;
      
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (mass[j] > mass_copy[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = mass_copy[j];
                mass_copy[j] = mass_copy[j + 1];
                mass_copy[j + 1] = tmp;
                noswap = 0;
            }
        }
        if (noswap == 1)
          
            break;
      
    }

    tmp = 0;
    //Нахождение максимального числа 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
        if (is_num_pef_sqrt(mass_copy[i]) == 1 && mass_copy[i] > tmp) {

           tmp = mass_copy[i];
           count++;
        
        }
    
    }
    //Если не нашлось ни одного полного квадрата
    if (tmp == 0 || count == 0) {
      
      printf("-1");

    }
    //Если нашлось, поиск индекса числа
    else{
      
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          if (mass[i] == tmp) {
        
              printf("%d", i);
              break;
          }

      }
      
    }
  
    return 0;
  
}
```

**Тесты**:

| Компиляция | Тест | Входные данные |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 1. Простой, квадрат один | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 2. Простой, квадратов два | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 3. Простой, нет квадратов | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 4. Ноль максимальный | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 5. Все нули | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 6. Один элемент, не квадрат | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 7. Один элемент, квадрат | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 8. MAX_ULL | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9_1. есть 9223372055222253009 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9_2. Есть 9223372055222253010 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9_3. Есть 9223372055222253008 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9_4. Есть 4503599627370497 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9_5. Есть 4503599761588224 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9n_1. Есть (2^32-1)^2-1 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9n_1. Есть (2^32-1)^2+1 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9n_3. Есть 10281932972584080889 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9n_3. Есть 10362782202483767809 | stdin |
| Visual Studio 2010 amd64 Release | 9n_3. Есть 10615801417945630201 | stdin |

Результат компиляции: compile - Visual Studio 2010 (64 bit) - ok

Пройдено 7/18 тестов, не известно какие.

Comment: А зачем сортировать? Идем себе по массиву, проверяем с использованием строгого неравенства, запоминаем наибольший...

Comment: @Harry действительно, это не повлияло, но мне казалось, что это оптимизирует программу.

Comment: Оптимизация O(N) до O(N log N)? :) А проверялка, кстати, доступна для всех? Чтоб поиграться? есть пара мыслей...

Comment: `x(i+1):=(x(i)+N/x(i))/2` - не такое ? @Harry

Comment: @Harry к сожалению, доступна не для всех, это вузовский сайт для практических работ, более того, сдавать можно раз в 3 часа, что ужасно замедляет весь процесс.

Comment: Ну и не будет проходить, пока Вы не перепишете is_num_pef_sqrt(long long int x) в целых числах. Равенство двух чисел типа double - вещь исключительно абстрактная.

Comment: @Ddd, как раз в этом месте сравнение `double` не приведёт к проблемам. Если `(double)x` не приводит к округлению, вычисления достаточно точные для правильного ответа.

Comment: Так ведь пребразование double(x) как раз и приведёт к потере младших разрядов. Они могут быть любыми, а сравнение двух double будет истинным.

Comment: @Ddd, младшие разряды будут потеряны только если число больше *2^53*. Для меньших чисел приведение и все вычисления точные.

Comment: Ну так специально и задали long long... К тому же, для стандартных математических функций допускается ошибка в младшем бите мантиссы, т.е. и для чисел меньших (1 << 53) правильный результат не гарантирован.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так можно (если с корнем не будет вычислительных проблем):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_num_pef_sqrt(unsigned long long x) {
        unsigned long long root = (unsigned long long) sqrt((double)x);
        return (root * root == x)? 1 : 0;
}


int main() {

    int n = 4;
    unsigned long long mass[4] = {1,9, (unsigned long long)4611686018427387904,4};
    int idx = -1;
    unsigned long long umax = 0;
    

    for (int i = n-1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (is_num_pef_sqrt(mass[i]) && mass[i] >= umax) {
           umax = mass[i];
           idx = i;
        }
        
    }
    printf("%d", idx);

}
```

Для нахождения целочисленного корня из uint64 [есть такой интересный подход](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18501209/844416)

```
 uint64_t y = sqrt(x) - 0x1p-20;
 if (2*y < x - y*y)
     ++y;
```

Comment: Специально же сделали массив long long, чтобы он в мантиссу double не вмещался.

Comment: @Ddd Ну вот и интересно,  что у них за тесты. Всё-таки учебная задача.

Comment: Я подам на вход  *2^60+1*. При приведении к `double` он округлится до *2^60*. А это полный квадрат. Вроде можно сделать ошибку и в другом направлении. Боюсь, без честного извлечения корня задача не решается.

Comment: Если приведение бед не натворило и вещественные вычисления по стандарту IEEE-754, то с `sqrt` вычислительных проблем не будет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy [Есть такой компактный трюк для вычисления целого корня](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499492/how-can-you-easily-calculate-the-square-root-of-an-unsigned-long-long-in-c/18501209#18501209) в смешанных float-int вычислениях

Comment: Спасибо! Я не знал про этот трюк. С ним всё работает за константу.